# ¿Cómo trabajar con signals (post_save) teniendo una relacion M2M?

Tags: python, django-models

El proyecto consiste en la creacion de eventos y a cada evento añadirle asistentes y que a esos asistentes les llegue una notificacion de que ha sido invitado a un determinado evento.

La tabla notificacion debe llenarse automaticamente al añadir los asistentes pero me presenta un error. A continuacion les detallo

En mi models.py estan los siguientes modelos

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save



class TimeStampModel(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True




class Evento(TimeStampModel):

Usuario=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
Titulo= models.CharField(max_length=140)
Descripcion= models.TextField(max_length=150)
Lugar= models.CharField(max_length=50)
Fecha=models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
Inicio= models.TimeField(default='00:00')
Fin= models.TimeField(default= '00:00')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Titulo





class Asistente(TimeStampModel):

Convocar = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, null=False)
Evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, blank=True, null=True)
Asistencia = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Evento.Titulo





class Notificacion(models.Model):

user= models.ManyToManyField(Asistente,blank=True, null=True)
evento =models.ForeignKey(Evento,blank=True, null=True)
estado=models.BooleanField(default=False)
timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Asistente)
def mensaje(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created',False):

        Notificacion.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

**Evento :** Es mi tabla que va a contener los datos de mi evento, como lo es el titulo, descripción, hora de inicio - fin, fecha  y el usuario, por esa razon este modelo tiene una relacion con el modelo USER de Django porque necesito almacenar al usuario que crea el evento.

**Asistente :** Es mi tabla que almacenara los invitados al evento, por esa razon tiene una relacion de *Muchos a Muchos* con el modelo USer de Django y tambien tiene una relacion *Foreinkey* con *Evento* para almacenar al evento que fueron asignados.

**Notificacion :** El campo *user* almacenara a los usuarios que fueron asignados en un evento, por esa razon es que tiene una relacion ***M2M*** con Asistente y tambien tiene una relacion con el modelo Evento para obtener la informacion del evento que fue invitado.

Utilizo el signal post_save para que automaticamente me registre la tabla de notificacion cada vez que asigno asistente a un evento y me da el siguiente error:
[image: Error al añadir asistentes]

Supongo que el campo user es invalido por la relacion M2M que tiene con Asistente ..

la verdad es que no se que pueda ser.

Hice la prueba cambiando el modelo notificacion y el sender al signal de esta manera:

```
class Notificacion(models.Model):

user= models.ForeignKey(user,blank=True, null=True)
evento =models.ForeignKey(Evento,blank=True, null=True)
estado=models.BooleanField(default=False)
timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Evento)
def mensaje(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created',False):

        Notificacion.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

Haciendolo asi  me llena la tabla Notificacion pero solamente los campos que no tienen una relacion .. es decir *estado* y *timestamp*, aqui ya me halle con otra duda ..

[image: Tabla Notificacion]

por eso mi suposicion es la relacion M2M :/

Nesecito ayuda..!! con lo del error y tambien el echo que no registra los otros campos... aahh y tambien de como trabajar esas notificaciones en tiempo real

corregir alguna cosa que halla echo mal, haganlo asi aprendo :)

Se los agradeceria muchisimo

Comment: Hola Evelyn, bienvenida a SOes, ¿podrías corregir los problemas de indentación? También, es mejor que muestres el Traceback completo del error, la imagen no ayuda mucho.

Comment: @César gracias por la bienvenida :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos pegas en la programación que estás haciendo:

1. Estás recogiendo la instancia de usuario con `kwargs.get('instance')` cuando ya la pasas como parámetro como `intance` (a secas)
2. Estás asignando un M2M como si fuese un campo de la tabla o un atributo de la clase, cuando a nivel de base de datos en la tabla notificacion no existe ya que Django crea una tabla de cruce para crear la relación entre notificacion y asistente. Por lo tanto, para crear la relación, tendrías que solucionarlo de esta manera:

   @receiver(post_save, sender=Asistente)

   def mensaje(sender, instance,**kwargs):

   ```
   if kwargs.get('created',False):
       notificacion = Notificacion()
       notificacion.user.add(instance)
   ```

Para entenderlo mejor, te recomiendo leer [esta página](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) de la documentación de Django